# Re-enconde mkv to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv, encoding

my mkv file was originally encoded using following encoder:

```
Lavf57.57.100
```

is it possible to reencode the same file without using it? Because I can't convert it to mp4, I get following error when I trying to encode *mkv* to *mp4*:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x3125100] Read error at pos. 2241497 (0x2233d9)
```

Comment: It is discouraged to crosspost [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201503/ffmpeg-error-convertimg-mkv-to-mp4) to multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: 2.6.8 is ancient. Upgrade and try again. You can download an already compiled binary from: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-encode certain video file, you doesn't need the previous encoder used to encode the file you have now.

You can either use FFmpeg or similar converter or use online services that'll provide conversion when you upload your file to their service.

Regarding the error message you get, it shows that file is corrupted in the time frame **pos. 2241497** . It isn't a problem with FFmpeg.

You can either search for FFmpeg option that'll let you skip certain frames while converting or there are some other converter programs which has the ability to skip error-some frames.

To verify this, try encoding different file.

**P.S**

*If you just need to change the container from **mkv** to **mp4**, you should try mp4 **Muxer** / **Re-Muxer** program. no need to re-encode. re-Muxer program will extract video data and audio data from your mkv file, then put it inside mp4 container. It'll only take few seconds (depending on your system's resources)*

Comment: I've tried to use -err_detect ignore_err, but the size of the generated file is too low and it doesn't play....i'e tried ffmpeg and avconv, but no luck, i get the same error, cause I've noticed that mkv files without this encode: Lavf57.57.100 - are converted successfully, I just can't find information about how it is doing

Comment: @BlurryScript Lavf is basically libavcodec which is part of ffmpeg project. Have you tried MeGUI or handbrake? those two provides nice GUI and it's easy to use them

Comment: but I need a converter for linux, just from a command line convertor without gui, is there any? but again how it will solve this error?

Comment: above both are available for linux. From the error message you posted, it seems it was a Read error. That means video file has some corrupt frames. Do you really need to convert? What is you trying to do here? Do you just need to convert the file for handheld device like ipod?

Comment: if i ignore these corrupted frames, the file size gets too low, almost empty, but the original file itself is playable, i mean why this happens? what exactly makes it corrupted? should I skip the files that are corrupted? or can be there a solution to convert it? cause it is working by itlsef

Comment: You didn't answer what I asked above. If you just need to play them on external device, you can just use a muxer, no need to convert. Both mkv and mp4 are just containers. Actual video conversation is done on video data and audio data.(Search for video codec types, Ex: H264/AVC, Xvid, mpeg-2 etc... Audio codec types being AAC, mp3, Ogg, vorbis, wav, wma,mp4a etc..) In video conversion process, converter transcodes video file and audio file separately, then putting it into a container(mkv, mp4, avi,mpg...) So if you just need to change the container(mkv to mp4) you should use muxer

Comment: You can just ignore only the corrupted frame, but to do that you may have to try little hard if use just CLI ffmpeg. or you can use video editing software like adobe premiere to just cut off the error-some frame.